# VIMでレジスタの内容をパイプしたい。

Tags: vim

:w !command とする時に、バッファではなくレジスタの内容を渡す方法はありますか？

Answer (score 4):

system() の第二引数にコマンドに渡す標準入力を設定できます。

```
:call system("my-command", @/)
```

この例ではコマンド my-command の標準入力に検索レジスタの内容を書き込んでいます。

Comment: mattnさんありがとうございました。